# CSS3 rotate not working in firefox and IE with 2 nested rotations

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've done an animation that currently works in -webkit browsers (safari,chrome) and Opera, but not in IE and firefox.

You can see the animation in action [here](http://www.csisanlorenzo.it/game/partita/?game=13).

There are 2 transformations, one applied to the field that works cross-browsers, and one applied to players that in firefox and IE looks like this:
[image]

But it should looks like (as in Chrome, Safari and Opera):[image]

Here are the rules applied to players:

```
  @-moz-keyframes giocatoreRot {
      from { -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
      to { -moz-transform: rotateX(-60deg); }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes giocatoreRot {
     from {-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
     to {-webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);}
  }

  /* all other browsers */
  @keyframes giocatoreRot {
    from {
       transform: rotateX(0deg);
       -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
     }
    to {
       transform: rotateX(-60deg);
       -ms-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    }
  }

  .giocatoreRot{
     height: 120px;
     z-index: 10;

     -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
     transform: rotateX(-60deg);

     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;

     -webkit-animation:giocatoreRot 2s linear;
     -moz-animation:giocatoreRot 2s linear;
     -o-animation:giocatoreRot 2s linear;
     -ms-animation:giocatoreRot 2s linear;
     animation:giocatoreRot 2s linear;      
   }
```

They are the same rules used for rotating #field. 
I haven't posted snippet because you can try different rules in the link above.

Comment: `preserve-3d` is not supported in IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform-style

Comment: +respect for testing in opera, go you!

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Doesn't Opera use webkit/blink now? Anyhow, apart from adding more time to testing it is quite useless to look at Opera.

Comment: @somethinghere yeah it uses Blink, it's almost identical to Chrome's engine but sometimes there's small inconsistencies.

Comment: Firefox and IE have the same behaviour; preserve-3d is not supported by IE, but fully supported by firefox. 
So why firefox has this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Add `perspective` on the parent.

**Example :** (to your `.contenitore`)

```
.contenitore {
   // ...
   perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Added also in the website so that you can check it.
It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: i dont see you added @Jacopo

Comment: I've deleted the animation for Firefox and IE because:
• IE doesn't support preserve-3d.
• Firefox has a completely different behaviour than other browsers